# Arduino making decision according to a packet received from serial port

Tags: arduino

The program listen to messages from serial port in the form  or  where first character (A or D) means analog or digital, the 2nd character - pin, the 3rd character - 1/0 or from 0 to 255. The markers < and > show the beginning and the end of packet.

For example, if packet  is received, the light is turned on by digitalWrite(13,1)
But nothing happens. When I send via serial monitor, for instance:  light is supposed to blink but it does not. The same with analogue outputs.

```
bool started = false;
bool ended = false;
char inData[5];
byte index;


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char inChar = Serial.read();


    if (inChar == '<')
    {
      index = 0;
      started = true;
      ended = false; 
    }

    else if (inChar == '>')
    {
      ended = true;
      break;
    }

    else
    {
      if (index <= 4)
      {
        inData[index] = inChar;
        index++;
      }
    }



     if (started && ended)
    {
      if (inData[0] == 'A')
      {
        pinMode(inData[2],OUTPUT);
        analogWrite(inData[2],inData[4]);
      }


      else if (inData[0] == 'D')
      {
        if (inData[4] == 1)
        {
          pinMode(inData[2],OUTPUT);
          digitalWrite(inData[2],HIGH);
        }

        else if (inData[4] == 0)
        {
           pinMode(inData[2],OUTPUT);
           digitalWrite(inData[2],LOW);
        }
      }
      started = false;
      ended = false;
      index = 0; 
    }

  }


Serial.println("Sending");  



}
```

Comment: The message looks like this <D,13,1> or <A,9,255>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will allow you to execute a method with an example serial string:

```
<power,led>
```

Once it processes this string, it'll execute the following method:

```
sendCommand(cmd, val);
```

See below for an example of how to turn on an LED on PIN 11.

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

int IRledPin = 11;

#define SOP '<'
#define EOP '>'

bool started = false;
bool ended = false;

char inData[80];
byte index;

void setup() {
  pinMode(IRledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Read all serial data available, as fast as possible
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char inChar = Serial.read();

    if (inChar == SOP) {
       index = 0;
       inData[index] = '\0';
       started = true;
       ended = false;
    } else if (inChar == EOP) {
       ended = true;
       break;
    } else {
      if (index < 79) {
        inData[index] = inChar;
        index++;
        inData[index] = '\0';
      }
    }
  }

  // We are here either because all pending serial
  // data has been read OR because an end of
  // packet marker arrived. Which is it?
  if (started && ended) {
    // The end of packet marker arrived. Process the packet
    char *cmd = strtok(inData, ",");

    if (cmd) {
       char *val = strtok(NULL, ",");
       if (val) {
          sendCommand(cmd, val);
       }
    }

    // Reset for the next packet
    started = false;
    ended = false;
    index = 0;
    inData[index] = '\0';
  }
}

void sendCommand(char *command, char *value) {
  if (strcmp(command,"power") == 0) {
    power(value);
  }
}

void power(char* value) {
  if (strcmp(value, "led") == 0) {
    digitalWrite(IRledPin, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the 2nd character is the pin, then you want `inData[1]` for your pin numbers instead of `inData[2]`.

Comment: <D,0,1> [0] is D, [1] is comma, [2] is 0.

Comment: You didn't specify that you're using commas.

Comment: Sorry. The message looks like this <D,13,1> or <A,9,255>

Comment: The problem then is that `inData[2]` for `<D,13,1>` is going to be the char representation of the char '1', which is actually 49.

Comment: Hm...How can I fix it? And why represenation of char '1"?

Comment: Because the number `1` is typed as a character, the same way you'd type `!`, `Q`, or `,`.  You'll need to input your entire array of chars, then convert it to a string, then use a string splitting method to get the individual items, then use an int parser to get the integers out of the substrings.

Comment: The data your reading in from the serial is in ASCII and comma separated too.  The index isn't counting the comma's.

Answer (score 1):

- Why do you go from `inData[0]` to `inData[2]`? Wouldn't the second character be in `inData[1]`?
- You're setting the `pinMode` to the actual value of `inData[2]`. That means to turn on pin 13, you need to send a carriage return character (`'\r'`).

Comment: What about comma in, for example, <D,1,0>

Answer (score -1):

The code doesn't run below but it should help you to sort out your problem.

What it tries to do is split the inData into the Tokens[] array.

It then turns the ASCII data into integers with the atoi() statement.

Hope it helps.

Got the splitter from [Segmentation Fault when using strtok_r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227198/segmentation-fault-when-using-strtok-r)

```
bool started = false;
bool ended = false;
char inData[5];
byte index;


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char inChar = Serial.read();


    if (inChar == '<')
    {
      index = 0;
      started = true;
      ended = false; 
    }

    else if (inChar == '>')
    {
      ended = true;
      break;
    }

    else
    {
      inData[index] = inChar;
      index++;
    }


     if (started && ended)
    {

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227198/segmentation-fault-when-using-strtok-r
// Splint up input data
    char *p = inData;
    char *tokens[50];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 50) {
      tokens[i] = strtok_r(p, ",", &p);
      if (tokens[i] == NULL) {
         break;
         }
      i++;
    }

    if (tokens[0] == '<A')
      {
        pinMode(tokens[1],OUTPUT);
        analogWrite(tokens[2],tokens[3]);
      }


      else if (token[0] == '<D')
      {
        if (atoi(token[3]) == 1)
        {
          pinMode(atoi(token[1]),OUTPUT);
          digitalWrite(atoi(token[1]),HIGH);
        }

        else if (atoi(tokens[3]) == 0)
        {
           pinMode(atoi(tokens[1]),OUTPUT);
           digitalWrite(atoi(tokens[1]),LOW);
        }
      }
      started = false;
      ended = false;
      index = 0; 
    }

  }
```

Comment: I get message "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer" about the line "if (tokens[0] == "A")

Comment: I think this is wrong:

if (token[0] == '<D')


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c